# regex in R - replace str

Tags: regex, r, gsub

i need replace "[", "]" and "[]" to "" using gsub in str

```
[{'link': 'http://www.proza.ru/avtor/churus', 'title': 'Личный сайт', 'id': 7}, {'link': 'https://www.facebook.com/Tanyachurus?ref=tn_tnmn', 'title': 'Facebook', 'id': 3}][]
```

Comment: `gsub('[][]', '', x)`

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- "[{'link': 'http://www.proza.ru/avtor/churus', 'title': 'Личный сайт', 'id': 7}, {'link': 'https://www.facebook.com/Tanyachurus?ref=tn_tnmn', 'title': 'Facebook', 'id': 3}][]"

gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x)
```

search of `[`or `]` and replace with `""`(nothing)

Comment: please note that you set variables in r
using the `<-` operator

Comment: oh the syntax ... thanks for pointing that out but the code will remain the same sir @Coder55

Comment: @Coder55 not necessarily, you can also use `=` to [assign](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) variables in R

Answer (score 2):

You just have to write:

```
value <- "[{'link': 'http://www.proza.ru/avtor/churus', 'title': 'Личный сайт', 'id': 7}, {'link': 'https://www.facebook.com/Tanyachurus?ref=tn_tnmn', 'title': 'Facebook', 'id': 3}][]"
gsub("\\[", "", value)
gsub("\\]", "", value)
```

Then there will be no such brackets in your string. 
You have to escape the brackets because otherwise, r is interpreting them as metasymbols and will throw an error.

Comment: when you try like this you get error:"Error in gsub("[", "", x) : 
  invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''"